# TightVNC full screen on multiple monitors?

Tags: macos, windows-10, multiple-monitors, vnc, tightvnc

I have a Mac, with two monitors, with Remote Management with VNC turned on.

I have a Windows 10 machine, with two monitors, running TightVNC client.

When I connect to the Mac, I get a wide window containing the displays of both monitors on the Mac. But when I maximize or go full screen in the TightVNC client, it maximizes to only one monitor, leaving one of the Mac's monitors inaccessible.

What I want is to have the full display of the Mac, both monitors included, displayed on the Win10 machine, using two monitors, without window borders or scroll bars.

I'm not seeing a way of accomplishing this.

Ideas?